# How can I write data in a single line on text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text-files

I am trying to write data in a .txt file using JavaScript function.
**My function :-**

```
function WriteToFile()
{
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var s = fso.CreateTextFile("test.txt", true);
    for(var j=1;j<9;j++)
    {
        if(document.getElementById('chk'+j).checked)
        {
            s.WriteLine('  ');
            s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('item'+j).innerText);
            s.WriteLine(',');
            s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('txtBx'+j).value);
            s.WriteLine(',');
            s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('txtBxx'+j).value);
            s.WriteLine(';');
        }
    }
    alert("written");
    s.Close();
}
```

Now the problem is that data being written on a new line.
(maybe because i am using s.WriteLine ?)
I want all the data to be written in a single line. how can i achieve this?

to elaborate more, my current output looks like this

```
abc
,
1
,
cdf
;

def
,
3
,
ehi
;
```

I want it like this-

```
abc,1,cdf;def,3,ehi;
```

Comment: try d.write and see if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `s.write()` instead of `s.writeLine()`. As the name implies, the second function is for writing whole lines, and it adds a newline after it.

Comment: worked, thanks a lot. i suspected s.writeline is the culprit but didn't know the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Just add everything to a variable then write the line.

```
var st = document.getElementById('item'+j).innerText;
st += ','
st += document.getElementById('txtBx'+j).value;
s.WriteLine(st);
```